# Translating ChainShape to world coordinates according to touch drag input

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to draw a ChainShape according to touch screen coordinates, however the coordinates are slightly off from my touch coordinates. I translate the chain drawn on the screen to world coordinates but don't think I've done it correctly.

I tried setting the shape's position to the first vertex but it positions it even further from the original touch coordinates. Can someone please help me understand where I'm going wrong?

```
public class Play implements Screen {
    private static final float TIMESTEP = 1 / 60f;
    private static final int VELOCITYITERATIONS = 8, POSITIONITERATIONS = 3;

    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private PolygonSpriteBatch batch;
    private World world;

    private List<Float> chain_verts = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private float[] chain;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0f, -9.81f), true);
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        batch  = new PolygonSpriteBatch();

        InputProcessor input_0 = new GestureDetector(new Gesture() {
        }) {
            @Override
            public boolean touchUp(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if (chain_verts.size() != 0) {
                    chain = new float[chain_verts.size()];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < chain_verts.size(); i++) {
                    chain[i] = chain_verts.get(i);
                    System.out.print(chain[i] + " ");
                }

                ChainShape chainShape = new ChainShape();
                chainShape.createChain(chain);

                Vector3 mouse = new Vector3();
                camera.unproject(mouse.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));

                BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
                bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
                bodyDef.position.set(mouse.x , mouse.y);

                FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
                fixtureDef.shape = chainShape;

                world.createBody(bodyDef).createFixture(fixtureDef);

                chain_verts.clear();
                chainShape.dispose();

                return super.touchUp(x, y, pointer, button);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDragged(float x, float y, int pointer) {
                chain_verts.add(x);
                chain_verts.add(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-y);
                return super.touchDragged(x, y, pointer);
            }
        };

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input_0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);

        camera.position.set(0, 20, 0);
        camera.update();

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = 1200;
        camera.viewportHeight = 800;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        debugRenderer.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you don't move the camera in your render method? Does it change the position of the shape?

Comment: The shape renders closer to the touch coordinates.

Comment: The closer I draw the shape to the bottom left corner of the screen the closer the shape is to the original coordinates. The closer to the center of the screen I draw the further away the shape is.

Comment: Try replacing `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` with `camera.viewportHeight`. If that doesn't work there's one more possible solution I have in store...

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only translating the starting coordinate and incorrectly setting the body's position to that coordinate. Instead I now translate each screen coordinate in `touchDragged()` before adding it to the `ArrayList` (chain_verts), works now. Also set starting position to `(0, 0)`.

```
public class Play2 implements Screen {
    private static final float TIMESTEP = 1 / 60f;
    private static final int VELOCITYITERATIONS = 8, POSITIONITERATIONS = 3;

    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private PolygonSpriteBatch batch;
    private World world;

    private List<Float> chain_verts = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private float[] chain;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0f, -9.81f), true);
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        batch  = new PolygonSpriteBatch();

        InputProcessor input_0 = new GestureDetector(new Gesture() {
        }) {

            @Override
            public boolean touchUp(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if (chain_verts.size() == 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    chain = new float[chain_verts.size()];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < chain_verts.size(); i++) {
                     chain[i] = chain_verts.get(i);
                }

                ChainShape chainShape = new ChainShape();
                chainShape.createChain(chain);

                BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
                bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
                bodyDef.position.set(0, 0);

                FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
                fixtureDef.shape = chainShape;

                world.createBody(bodyDef).createFixture(fixtureDef);

                chain_verts.clear();
                chainShape.dispose();

                return super.touchUp(x, y, pointer, button);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDragged(float x, float y, int pointer) {
                // translate each coordinate here before adding to vertices list
                Vector3 mouse = new Vector3();
                camera.unproject(mouse.set(x, y, 0));

                chain_verts.add(mouse.x);
                chain_verts.add(mouse.y);

                return super.touchDragged(x, y, pointer);
            }
        };

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input_0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = 1200 / 30;
        camera.viewportHeight = 800 / 30;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        debugRenderer.dispose();
    }
}
```